# Using local variable as src on iframe

Tags: php, variables, iframe, src

I need to use the output in the variable $data and put it inside an iframe (or other perhaps) so as to scroll it properly. Please, find the mistake in the following code:

```
    <?php

    $url = 'http://lema.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=IwxflJmT9DXX2DMkYs8Z';

    $css = <<<EOT

    <style type="text/css">
     body
       {
       background: #eeeeee;
       }
     .a
       {
        color: green;
       }
    .f
       {
        font-size: 200%;
       }
    .o
       {
        font-size: 80%;
        }
    img
        {
        visibility:hidden;
         }

    </style>
    EOT;

    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    $data = str_replace('</head>', $css.'</head>', $data);
    echo "<iframe id='first' src='$data'
          frameborder='0' 
          width='400px' 
          height='300px' 
          scrolling='yes'
          border-style: none;></iframe>";
    ?>
```

The problem is probably on the last lines. Instead of the word's definition to appear inside the iframe, an error shows up, saying the object hasn't been found Thanks!
[image]

Comment: You haven't told us what the problem is.  What doesn't work?

Comment: instead of the word's definition to appear inside the iframe, an error shows up, saying the object hasn't been found

Comment: Please put the explanation of what doesn't work in the body of the question, as well as the exact error message you get, rather than a paraphrase of it.

Comment: @JuanmaAlonso - try changing the iframe attributes as i have posted in answer and let me know if your problem is solved !

Comment: @JuanmaAlonso- and is it necessary to use <<EOT??

Comment: @PankitKapadia it's an instruction i copied from another tutorial. It works if i didn't want to put everything inside another object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `<iframe>` to the iframe code given below.:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://lema.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=IwxflJmT9DXX2DMkYs8Z';

$css = <<<EOT

<style type="text/css">
 body
   {
   background: #eeeeee;
   }
 .a
   {
    color: green;
   }
.f
   {
    font-size: 200%;
   }
.o
   {
    font-size: 80%;
    }
img
    {
    visibility:hidden;
     }

</style>
EOT;

$data = file_get_contents($url);
$data = str_replace('</head>', $css.'</head>', $data);
/*u have to change src like this. and you need to add style attribute to use border-style: none;
   /* echo "<iframe id='first' src='".$data."'
      frameborder='0' 
      width='400px' 
      height='300px' 
      scrolling='yes'
      style='border-style:none;'></iframe>"; */
//Remove this iframe and simply echo $data
echo '<div style="overflow:scroll;">'.$data.'</div>'; //YOU CAN USE AUTO instead of SCROLL
?>
```

The output what i am getting is as below:(i have set `height:200px; width:500px;`)

[image]

Comment: i copied the code just as you wrote but still it shows up "object not found"

Comment: @JuanmaAlonso - its showing me `Forbidden` error showing that `You don't have permission to access /<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/drae/css/I.drae.css+estilosCabDrae.css,Mcc.W_CzH9ApGk.css.pagespeed.cf.w1GLVsE-IR.css"><TITLE>Real Academia EspaÃ±ola. Diccionario Usual.</TITLE><style type="text/css"> body { background: on this server.`

Comment: yes, there is no permission, but there must be a way to put $data into an object or something more editable. If i just leave echo $data , it works, i can change the font and everything, but i would like to put everything together, simply on one object, doesn't have to be an iframe. And, if i link the iframe to $url, it works, but my css changes don't take place....

Comment: @JuanmaAlonso - i think you just want to change some css of that url page and show it onto your page. You can't show it using `<iframe>` because `file_get_contents()` will return the contents of that url and not the **URL** what you will need in `src`. So just `echo $data;` instead of `<iframe></iframe>`.

Comment: @JuanmaAlonso - let me know is it what exactly wanted??

Comment: @JuanmaAlonso - check the updated code with `<div>`. Specify `width` and `height` as you want

Answer (score 2):

the `src` attribute on an `<iframe/>` element takes a URL, not HTML source....

i'm not entirely sure what you want to do, but perhaps you just need to `echo` your `$data` ?

Comment: so should be then (...) src='$url' ??

Comment: well, that will work, but it will load the original page, without your CSS additions

Comment: so how is the complete way, including my CSS additions ??

Comment: did you try just `echo $data;`?  you might have a bit to work through, still, but that seems to be what you're after?

Comment: it works if i echo $data but my goal is to paste $data inside an iframe, so i can scroll through the output, change the border-radius, etc....

Comment: an iframe will load content from a URL.  if you want to inject _content_ directly into an iframe, I suggest you use a javascript approach (see, e.g., here: http://sparecycles.wordpress.com/2012/03/08/inject-content-into-a-new-iframe/)

Comment: are you sure there isn't any simpler way? there is no problem if i use some other object replacing the iframe, a form for example, or something that admits a variable as a source

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20733/discussion-between-simon-and-juanma-alonso)

Comment: @JuanmaAlonso - if you want scrolling you can use `<div>` and `echo $data` into that div and use `overflow:scroll;` property of `style`.

Comment: @JuanmaAlonso - code is changed. Checkout my answer with the output i am getting.